# Infinite loop trying to validate/save

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm using Yii framework to create a really simple 1 text-area field and 2 hidden inputs with predefined values sent from the server.

The way it should work is *as expected*, I mean, you write something on that text-area and you click on the *send* button. An ajax validation is made (only requisite for the text-area is that is shouldn't be empty) and if validated, save the data and redirect to some other page.

The problem is that it won't save any data if validation error was triggered.

I mean, if I go to the page, write something and hit on the *send* button, data will be saved and I'll be redirected correctly. But if I go to the page, hit the *send* button (without typing anything in the text-area), wait for the error to appear (note that this is done via ajax, so no page-reload here), write something and hit *send* again Yii is going to start making a request after a request in an infinite loop.

I already have checked the data being sent, and everything is fine (both data and action-url).

Here is my Controller code

```
public function actionView($id)
{

    $user = Usuario::model()->findByAttributes(
        array(
            'nick'=>Yii::app()->user->getId()
        )
    );

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Mensaje', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'with'=>array('usuario', 'usuario.detallesusuario'),
            'condition'=>'Tema_idtema='.$id
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>1000,
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        'usuario_id'=>$user->idusuario,
        'tema_id'=>$id,
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));

}

public function actionCreateMessage(){

    $model=new Mensaje;

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Mensaje']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Mensaje'];
        $model->fecha_hora=new CDbExpression('NOW()');

        $model->save();

        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$model->Tema_idtema));
    }

}
```

And the code from the View

```
<?php 

$model = new Mensaje();
echo $this->renderPartial('_mensaje_form', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'usuario_id'=>$usuario_id,
        'tema_id'=>$tema_id,
    ), 
    false, //return instead of echo
    true //post-process
);

?>
```

Here is the "_mensaje_form" code

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'mensaje-form',
    'action'=>CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('tema/createMessage')),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,
        'validateOnType'=>false,
    ),
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row" style="margin:20px 5px 0 176px;">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mensaje'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'mensaje',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'mensaje'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'Tema_idtema', array('value'=>$tema_id)); ?>      
    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'Usuario_idusuario', array('value'=>$usuario_id)); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons" style="margin:-3px 0 -8px 176px;">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Responder' : 'Guardar'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Any idea why I'm getting that loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you,

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10427-ajax-clientscript/

in your view, the last parameter "true" in renderPartial may be the problem.

Comment: remove that parameter completely (for time being) and try.

Comment: You're right! This was causing the error! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess (a bit long shot) that **form id** in your `preformAjaxValidation()` might be wrong, so it causes the loop! since it won't get in the body of the `if` and hence executes `Yii::app()->end();` !!

Check it in your **controller**:

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='exact-form-id')//should be mensaje-form
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

Comment: My ```performAjaxValidation``` method looks exactly like this one.

Comment: Ok, try checking with firebug to examine the behavior of the ajax request. dose it actually fires? is it part of the infinite loop or not?

Comment: I think you lost me on that one :s . The form is making a few request each second, so I'd say yes, the ajax request gets fired. The whole infinite loop is that the form is doing a request after a request and all of them contain correct data, and the result of each one is "[]" (passes validation)